# Mean error of finite differences derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, finite-difference-method

I wrote a module that computes the 4-th order finite difference derivative of a function at $N$ equidistant points of an interval and the difference between the exact and numerical value at those points, and tested it on the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. I would then like to show that the mean error $<e>= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N} |e_i|$ (where $e_i$ is the difference at the $i$-th point of the interval) decreases proportionally with $N^{-4}$, by experimenting with different values for $N$. I chose $N=\{2^4,2^5,...,2^{15}\}$, but the computation is very slow and the listplot does not even show that the mean error decreases proportionally with $N^{-4}$, why does all that happen? Thanks in advance!

```
der4[gridpoints_,values_,order_]:= Module[{x=gridpoints, y=values, k=order}, 
de=NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[k],N[x],"DifferenceOrder"->4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"//Normal; de.N[y]]
number=31;
f[x_]:=Exp[-8*x^2];
grid=Subdivide[-1, 1, number];
val=f[grid];
approx=der4[grid,val,1]
difference=approx-f'[grid];
ListPlot[difference, PlotLabel->"Difference between numerical and analytical solution for f(x)", AxesLabel->{x, "Difference"}]

Num=ConstantArray[0.,12];
Do[Num[[n]]=2^(n+3), {n, 1, 12}];
err=ConstantArray[0.,12];
Do[grid1=Subdivide[-1, 1, Num[[n]]]; err[[n]]=(1/Num[[n]])*Total[Abs[der4[grid1,f[grid1],1]-f'[grid1]]], {n, 1, 12}];
ListPlot[Transpose[{Num^(-4), err}], AxesLabel->{"N^(-4)","Mean error"}, PlotLabel->"Mean error decrease"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: To speed it up, get rid of the `Normal`.  The `SparseArray` representation of your very large differentiation matrix is your friend. Otherwise for `n = 11, 12` you spend most of the time swapping (my memory usage said 15+GB).  If I use `ListLogLogPlot`, I see the decrease, up to a point that's probably expected.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you!